# How to remove unwanted packages from node_modules? npm rm doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm

I can't for the life of me figure out an easy way to remove packages from node_modules.

I'm following along a tutorial where it tells me to use `npm rm <pkg>`, but when I verify that I performed the action correctly, it says that dependencies are still lying around. I looked in my root directory and noticed that although the package was deleted from my package.json, it's still there in my node_modules directory. Why doesn't `npm rm <pkg>` actually remove the package like I imagine it's supposed to? What is the other solution? I suppose I can delete my node_modules directory entirely, but that wouldn't work if I had other dependencies/packages that I relied on.

I've tried googling for the answer, but strangely nothing comes up.

Answer (score 4):

`npm uninstall`  removes the module from node_modules, but not package.json.

`npm uninstall <pkg> --save` will also delete the dependency from package.json.

`npm rm <pkg>` removes the packages when uninstall not working

`npm prune <pkg>` for extraneous packages

If you don't want to uninstall one by one run

```
rm -rf pkg-name && npm cache clean && npm install
```